# Write integration tests for Go CLI asking series of questions/answers for Windows

Tags: go, lua, command-line-interface

I have a command line app for windows (that asks a series of questions via command line) developed in Golang and I would like to write integration tests for this app. I looked at https://github.com/zetamatta/expect. It can simulate output for each question asked. Example:

```
expect("Enter installer name")
send("xxx\r")
expect("Execute it?")
send("y\r")
..
..
..
```

The golang app does some processing based on the various questions asked and their answers. It does install some stuff. If I were to write integration tests using this package, how does it indicate if it was a pass or a fail?

My lua script is like:

```
echo(true)
if spawn([[C:\test.exe]]) then
    expect("Enter installer name?")
    echo(true)
    send("xxx\r")
    expect("Install it?")
    send("y\r")
    expect("~]$")
    echo(true)
    send("exit\r")
end
```

I execute as:

```
expect.exe sample.lua
```

It works fine and automatically takes the above inputs for the questions without having to manually enter any. However, at the end, how do I organize this as a test to show that everything passed successfully or failed. Eventually, I will need to write several tests like that for all possible and negative scenarios.

Comment: What are your success/failure conditions? Are you are handling your "failure" conditions within the expect script itself? If you can test for "success" by an observable side effect after the expect script has run, then you could simply test for that side effect after running expect.